# can i access / edit files on usb drive from local mamp php application

Tags: apache, mamp, mamp-pro

How can I access / edit files on usb drive from mamp php application that is on my main harddrive ?

It is obviously very dooable in php when the files are in the same folder structure as the php file that is doing the processing but I have not found a solution to the edit files on usb drive.

Basically I will have a usb key full of pictures that I will need to sort into different folders via my php application.

Comment: You'd have to give the files and directories proper permissions in order for the webserver to access them. Other than that it's just a matter of picking the right path on your filesystem.

Comment: thanks for reply - so how do i set the right path in mamp setup ?

Comment: you just provide the path to the files (like /mnt/yourusbkey/somefolder) as you see it on your system once the usb key is mounted to usual php filesystem functions like opendir(), glob()... Then, if any error occur, check for permissions for the webserver user on the folder/files, or the mount itself. Please note nothing in your question is specifically php related.

Comment: nope dont seem to work - the USB is called DATA and i have tried $s=scandir ('/DATA'); and dont work :(

Comment: so im thinking it is not possible ?